# Python Pandas groupby, rank, then assign value based on custom rank

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe, ranking

**Problem Setup**

The pandas Dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'Subgroup': ['Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2'], 'Keyword': ['kw 1', 'kw 1', 'kw 1', 'kw 2', '+kw +2', 'kw 2', 'kw 3', 'kw 3', 'kw 3'], 'Normalized': ['kw 1', 'kw 1', 'kw 1', 'kw 2', 'kw 2', 'kw 2', 'kw 3', 'kw 3', 'kw 3'], 'Criterion Type': ['Exact', 'Phrase', 'Broad', 'Phrase', 'Broadified', 'Exact', 'Broad', 'Exact', 'Phrase'], 'Max CPC': [1.62, 1.73, 0.87, 1.70, 0.85, 1.60, 0.99, 1.58, 1.68], 'CPC Rank': [2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1], 'Type Rank': [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2]})
```

This to get the columns in the right spot:

```
df = df[['Group', 'Subgroup', 'Keyword', 'Normalized', 'Criterion Type', 'Max CPC', 'CPC Rank', 'Type Rank']]
```

**The goal**

`groupby` `['Group', 'Subgroup', 'Normalized']`, then `rank` the `Max CPC`s.  Next, I want to map the `Max CPC` associated to the `CPC Rank` to the `Type Rank` which is determined based on `Criterion Type` and my own custom rank:
`{'Exact':1, 'Phrase':2, 'Broadified':3, 'Broad':4}`

[image]

The result would be the `New CPC` column with its appropriate `Max CPC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'Subgroup': ['Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2'], 'Keyword': ['kw 1', 'kw 1', 'kw 1', 'kw 2', '+kw +2', 'kw 2', 'kw 3', 'kw 3', 'kw 3'], 'Normalized': ['kw 1', 'kw 1', 'kw 1', 'kw 2', 'kw 2', 'kw 2', 'kw 3', 'kw 3', 'kw 3'], 'Criterion Type': ['Exact', 'Phrase', 'Broad', 'Phrase', 'Broadified', 'Exact', 'Broad', 'Exact', 'Phrase'], 'Max CPC': [1.62, 1.73, 0.87, 1.70, 0.85, 1.60, 0.99, 1.58, 1.68], 'CPC Rank': [2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1], 'Type Rank': [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2]})
df = df[['Group', 'Subgroup', 'Keyword', 'Normalized', 'Criterion Type', 'Max CPC', 'CPC Rank', 'Type Rank']]

#Sort by custom priority based on their Criterion Type
df = df.sort(['Group', 'Subgroup', 'Normalized', 'Type Rank'])
#Reset index and drop old one
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
#Create df1 which is a Series of the Max CPC column in its correctly ranked order
df1 = df.sort(['Group', 'Subgroup', 'Normalized', 'CPC Rank'])['Max CPC']
#Reset index and drop old one
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df1)

#Add the df1 Series to df and name the column New CPC
df['New CPC'] = df1

print(df)
```

This is by far the most efficient solution to this problem.  The hard part was realizing that I could `sort` `df` by the `Type Rank` so the `Criterion Type` rows were ordered by their rank.  This meant I wanted the highest `Max CPC` to apply to the first, the second highest `Max CPC` to the second, and so on.

Then all I had to do was create a `Max CPC` `Series` sorted by `CPC Rank`.

Lastly, add this `Series` to the existing `df`.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted the values inside each group and assigned the sorted values using index.
Is this what you want?

```
df['new CPC'] = -1
parts = []
grouped = df.groupby(['Group', 'Subgroup', 'Normalized'])
for name, group in grouped:
    type_rank_index = group.sort(columns='Type Rank').index
    cpc_rank_index = group.sort(columns='CPC Rank').index
    group.loc[type_rank_index, 'new CPC'] = group.loc[cpc_rank_index, 'Max CPC']
    parts.append(group)

result = pd.concat(parts)
```

Comment: When I try your example, in the end, `Max CPC` equals `new CPC` which shouldn't happen because I'm trying to reassign `Max CPC`s based on their `CPC Rank` and the Keyword's `Criterion Type`.

Comment: @Jarad sorry I couldn't understand your requirement. Please explain it again clearly and I'll change my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
def group_rank(df):
    # first of all you've to rank according to `Max CPC`
    df['CPC Rank'] = df['Max CPC'].rank(ascending = False)
    # create the mapping
    mapping = pd.Series(data=df['Max CPC'].values , index= df['CPC Rank'].values)
    # create new column according to your ranking
    df['New CPC'] = df['Type Rank'].map(mapping)
    return df

df.groupby(['Group', 'Subgroup', 'Normalized']).apply(group_rank)
```

Comment: `mapping` contains an index with non-unique values.  When defining `New CPC`, `map(mapping)` seems to cause a `pandas.core.index.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` error.  Your function works in my example `df` but I get `InvalidIndexError` on my larger dataset.  Also, when I define `mapping` not in a function, then do `df['New CPC'] = df['Type Rank'].map(mapping)`, it also raises the error.  Does this type of mapping only work in a function?  Either way, I'll need to study this. Thanks for the concept.

Comment: This means you have duplicate values of Type rank for each group , is this right ? If so how should you map your values in this case ?

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility (rare/infrequent but still a possibility).  The `Type Rank` numbers are derived based on my own custom rank: `{'Exact':1, 'Phrase':2, 'Broadified':3, 'Broad':4}`.  This custom rank is based on the `Criterion Type` and it is possible for two rows in the same group to be `Broadified` which maps to `3` as the `Type Rank`.  In these few cases, the best way to rank them would be based on the + signs in the `Keyword` column - the more + signs, the lower the rank, the fewer + signs, the higher the rank. Ex: +kw +2 = `Type Rank` 2, +kw 2, = `Type Rank` 3.