# pandas how to add ranking value after grouping

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, pandas, grouping, ranking

I have been trying to figure out how to update the rank column based on the value in column 'Total LCQI Impact' where the largest value would be rank 1 and so forth.

After I groupby the dataFrame it looks like the following:

```
>>> avgs


     Impact
Period start Period end zone usid     site id       rank        Total LCQI Impact  LTE BLOCK Impact  LTE DROP Impact  LTE TPUT                                                                             
03/05/2016   03/11/2016 69A  8613.0   MOL03804      0           0.002962          0.000840         0.001704         0.000417
                             8614.0   MOL01034      0           0.003745          0.001141         0.001992         0.000612
                             8634.0   MOL03838      0           0.002568          0.000234         0.000504         0.001830
                             8640.0   MOL03846      0           0.003238          0.000772         0.000567         0.001899
                             8644.0   MOL01129      0           0.002272          0.000739         0.000788         0.000745
                             8645.0   MOL03854      0           0.002476          0.000457         0.000672         0.001347
```

my question is how do I update the rank column as mentioned above?

I thought something like this would work but it doesn't:

```
avgs['rank'] = avgs.sort('Total LCQI Impact', ascending=False).rank()
```

Comment: What is the output that you get from the line of code that doesn't work? And how does that differ from what you are trying to get?

Comment: I think you want an approach similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32421313/1552748